# Dynamically enable/disable select tag

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-select

I am trying to enable the department select tag when the value of send to select tag is other than "global" using knockoutjs. But for some reason the department select tag is stuck to initial enable/disable state. Dynamical enable/disable works for other elements e.g. textarea

**Select which determines the enable/disable state of the other**

`<select data-bind="options: recipientSelector, optionsText: 'name',value: selectedRecipient">`

**The select tag which needs to be disabled/enabled**

`<select data-bind="options: department_name"></select>`

**Javascrpt ViewModel**

```
var SendMessageModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.to = ko.observableArray();
        this.to_all = ko.observable();
        this.title = ko.observable();
        this.message = ko.observable();
        this.recipientSelector = [
            { recipient: "global", name: "To All" },
            { recipient: "custom", name: "Custom" }
        ];
        this.selectedRecipient = ko.observable();
        this.department_name = ['CSE', 'ECE', 'EE'];
        self.disableSelects = ko.pureComputed(function () {

            return self.selectedRecipient().recipient == "global";
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new SendMessageModel());
```

[Screenshot "Custom" option enables "Department" select element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BULLz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enable` binding in combination with your `selectedRecipient` observable like so:

```js
var SendMessageModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.to = ko.observableArray();
  this.to_all = ko.observable();
  this.title = ko.observable();
  this.message = ko.observable();
  this.recipientSelector = [
    { recipient: "global", name: "To All" },
    { recipient: "custom", name: "Custom" }
  ];
  this.selectedRecipient = ko.observable();
  this.department_name = ['CSE', 'ECE', 'EE'];
  self.disableSelects = ko.pureComputed(function () {

    return self.selectedRecipient().recipient == "global";
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new SendMessageModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="
  options: recipientSelector, 
  optionsText: 'name',
  value: selectedRecipient"></select>

<select data-bind="
  options: department_name,
  enable: selectedRecipient().recipient === 'custom'"></select>
```

You could also use the `visible` binding. This might still be a bit confusing since the second `select` still kind of shows a default selection.

Comment: Nope. This still doesn't work. The problem is only with select tags, all other fields seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enable` with the computed that's already in the view model:

```
<select data-bind="options: department_name, enable: disableSelects"></select>
```

See [demo](http://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010)

This adds a disabled attribute to the select tag. How it looks visually will be dependent on your UI styles/framework.